# How to check each value in a pandas column contains a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if a column that contains a list of dictionaries contains a specific key.

```
In [128]: das.properties
Out[128]: 
0        [{'aon_uuid': 'ab8acae5fe37448589094f40...
1        [{'aon_uuid': '3e8e218a695240af823ea459...
2        [{'aon_uuid': 'd82085052cac4e888a79046f...
3        [{'aon_uuid': 'f4af2f4e085944a8b2cfa8ba...
4        [{'aon_uuid': '306c5229ebdb4abb8242bd33...
                               ...                        
35771    [{'aon_uuid': 'b472a9eac4f84ec1ad83db85...
35772    [{'aon_uuid': '237473f54ad94759a7914fbe...
35773    [{'aon_uuid': 'b79e683015374126b8f1a796...
35774    [{'aon_uuid': 'c0e08e43b8b84c40848e84ee...
35775    [{'aon_uuid': '452256b4fde744bf820100eb...
```

How can I assert that each column contains a `aon_uuid`? I want to assert if any of these rows in the `properties` column does not contain that uuid.

I have tried using `isin` but i don't think it worked with a dictionary as values :(

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import ChainMap

df.properties.map(lambda x: ChainMap(*x)).str.contains('aon_uuid', regex=False)
```

`ChainMap` will join list of dictionaries, `.str.contains` then checks if the key is in the resulting dict.

Alternative: do it explicitly

```
df.properties.map(lambda l: any('aon_uuid' in d for d in l))
```

To check if all values have the key, just add `.all()` at the end:

```
df.properties.map(lambda l: any('aon_uuid' in d for d in l)).all()
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks Marat!!! and to check they are all "True" I guess I could just do something with `unique`? Sorry still a noob with pandas!

Comment: @caasswa just add `.all()` at the end. Added to the answer